# How important is it to use a real flare nut wrench when removing the fuel line on an old Ford tractor?

Tags: ford, tools, tractor

An [article on overhauling the carbs](http://www.ytmag.com/articles/restore/8ncarb/artint231_pg1.htm) on a Ford 8N tractor says to use a flare nut wrench to disconnect the fuel line. How important is it use that kind of wrench, vs. an open ended wrench?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a flare nut wrench (aka line wrench) should be used if it is calling for it.

The reasoning for using a flare wrench over an open ended wrench is that you can grip all sides of the fitting just like you can with a box wrench but the opening at the end of the wrench allows you to slip over the connected hose/line unlike a box wrench.

This allows you to apply more torque with less likeliness of slipping and rounding it off.

Depending on the size and material the fitting is made from, it can be very easy to round off, the flare wrench lowers that chance.

Comment: Fuel lines are almost always made out of aluminum, which as you may know is a fairly soft metal.  Very easy to round off with standard wrenches if it's at all stuck.

Comment: The fittings themselves are more likely to be brass, but same idea – soft metal needs support.